# F# multiple one to many relationship

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I am trying to learn F# and I came across this question:

let's say I have three tables. A,B,C

How do i create a type if 1A -> ManyB, then 1B -> ManyC

I mean in C# you can create a list of B in A object. then create a list of C in B object.
What about in F#?
I can't really find any example regarding this on the internet.
Any advises are welcome and Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you provide specific C# code just for clarity?

Comment: @LSM07 Actually, I just realized I wasn't thinking straight. I don't think my scenario was valid. but just for clarity, I was thinking about something like A object contains B list and C list. my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to give a good answer, because your question is way too general. The answer will depend on what you actually want to do with those objects.

However, if you just want a value to keep a list of other values, you can define those types as F# records containing lists:

```
type C = { Whatever : string }
type B = { CThings : C list }
type A = { BThings : B list }
```